# Security implications of chroot()

Tags: permissions, security, ftp, chroot, vsftpd

I want to setup a small FTP server for personal use, and decided to use `vsftpd` for that. I thought that I should enable `chroot_local_user`, so users are chrooted to their home directory upon login. Although all users should not have read access outside their home directory, you are never safe from mistakes, right?

But `man vsftpd.conf` says:

```
chroot_local_user
    If set to YES, local users will be (by default) placed in a chroot() jail in
    their home directory after login.  Warning: This option has security
    implications, especially if the users have upload permission,  or  shell
    access.  Only enable if you know what you are doing.  Note that these
    security implications are not vsftpd specific. They apply to all FTP daemons
    which offer to put local users in chroot() jails.
```

What "security implications" do they mean? Do I have to remove the write permission of each user on it's home directory? Why is that? I can't imagine it's safer to not use chroot than to use it...

Comment: It is not that is unsafer than the alternative solution, it is just that is not perfect isolation and chroots can be broken.

Comment: I have worked for a $1b+ company that did exactly this... on the other hand, I would hardly say that made it the best idea...

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a chroot jail that almost impossible to break out of, but that wont stop an attacker doing things such as gaining local network access or sending spam or forcing the system into a bot net. A chroot jail will keep them from getting root access but plenty of damage can be done from a standard user account. If the server is only for personal use than chroot should be more than enough security IMHO.